# Java: Inheritance of concrete empty instance methods

Tags: java, oop

The question is considered as a general Object Oriented Design question and not related to any specific case for now.

Let's say I have a test library which has an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractTest<E extends Event> {

    private ProcessingService service = new ProcessingService();

    protected static abstract void buildTestData();

    public void testSomething(Event event) {
        beforeScenario(event);

        service.process(event);

        // ... asserts and other actions

        afterScenario(event);
    }

    protected void beforeScenario(E event) {
        // override if needed
    }

    protected void afterScenario(E event) {
        // override if needed
    }
}
```

Each class derived from `AbstractTest` is forced to provide `buildTestData()` implementation and optionally could provide its own `beforeScenario` and `afterScenario`.

Having such empty methods has it's own pros and cons from my point of view. You don't make derived classes to `@Override` optional methods as opposed to abstract methods. Also you ensuring proper order of calling the scenarios in case when derived class overrides them and uses `testSomething` from abstract class:

```
public class SpecificTest extends AbstractTest<SomeEvent> {

    protected static void buildTestData() {
        // build test data
    }

    // override only scenarious and do not touch testSomething()
    protected void beforeScenario(E event) {
        // construct
    }

    protected void afterScenario(E event) {
        // destroy
    }
}
```

On the other hand these empty concrete methods look weird in parent class. Derived class can `@Override testSomething` like:

```
public class SpecificTest extends AbstractTest<SomeEvent> {

    protected static void buildTestData() {
        // build test data
    }

    // assuming that you don't have these methods in parent classes
    public void testSomething(Event event) {
        beforeScenario(event);

        super.testSomething(event);

        afterScenario(event);
    }


    private void beforeScenario(E event) {
        // construct
    }

    private void afterScenario(E event) {
        // destroy
    }
}
```

**Which approach is more appropriate from OOD point of view?**

**Does it make sense to to keep such empty methods in parent classes at all?**

Comment: Maybe opinionated - If there is no default implementation and if you don't want to force classes to provide one, you can leave them empty. At the very least, you can add a log message stating that you are no-oping

Comment: If it's going to be common for sub-classes to override, then the first approach, and mark `testSomething(Event event)` as `final`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. Your code structure resembles that of a [Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

A template pattern implementation would look like (taken from Head First Design Patterns)

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
    final void templateMethod() {
       primitiveOperation1();
       primitiveOperation2();
       concreteOperation();
       hook();
    }
    abstract void primitiveOperation1();
    abstract void primitiveOperation2();

    final void concreteOperation() {
      //implementation 
    }
    void hook() { }
}
```

The `primitiveOperations` are abstract and *must* be overridden by the subclass whereas the `concreteOperation` is marked final and cannot be overridden.
We also have a concrete method called `hook` which does nothing by default.  The subclasses can choose to override it or decide not to. These methods are called hooks.

So, when comparing your code with this

- `buildTestData` is a `primitiveOperation`
- `testSomething` is `concreteOperation`
- `beforeScenario` and `afterScenario` are `hooks`